# Is it a Cyclic number?

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic

A cyclic number is a number of "n" digits that when multiplied by 1, 2, 3,...n, results in the same digits but in a different order.

For example, the number 142,857 is a cyclic number since 142,857 x 2 = 285,714, 142,857 x 3 = 428,571, 142,857 x 4 = 571,428, and so on. Given an integer input, determine if it is a cyclic number by outputting a truthy value if it is, and a falsy value if not.

Also, to be clear, the input can contain leading 0's: e.g. 0344827586206896551724137931

This is due to the fact that if leading zeros are not permitted on numerals, then 142857 is the only cyclic number in decimal.

Since it is code-golf, shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: Hi and welcome to PPCG. This is not a bad question, but if you take a look at some of the recently posted questions I think that you will see that it could be better. Specifically, it would be very beneficial for the community if you provided more test cases to work with. When posting future challenges, please consider using the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/31625).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>9</s> 6 bytes

Thanks to *Emigna* for saving 3 bytes!

```
ā*€{ïË
```

Explanation:

```
ā        # Push range(1, len(input) + 1)
 *       # Multiply by the input
  €{     # Sort each element
    ï    # Convert to int to remove leading zeros
     Ë   # Check if all elements are equal
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#BcE7EYBQDARAP1T5XC6JNiposcIMIh5KMBJ25z2277z39axrRpSN1rCAeVqVekS7mbhXl0tIIRFJS9UiIMxsUn8)

Comment: What is the reason for `¦‚˜`?

Comment: @kalsowerus If the input has a leading zero, multiplying by 1 would make it disappear, which makes it not work for `0588235294117647`.

Comment: @Adnan why didn't 0169491525423728813559322033898305084745762711864406779661 work?

Comment: @tfbninja Oh okay, is adding leading zeroes after the multiplication also something to take into account? [These are the individual sorted results](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#BcG5EYAwDATAfoj0nqTaSIAyPMREdEDmIaMLN2J257sv/Rpb@85x3Gt/5iRGWbGLm2hIJqt7qQipZqWSU1qYBySYE2aEiAL4Bw) I get after multiplying, with some missing leading zeroes, which would probably indicate the problem here.

Comment: @Adnan Yup, that's the problem! Definitely take the leading zeroes into account. Good Luck!

Comment: @tfbninja Thanks for the notification, fixed.

Comment: @Adnan, Nice Job! Works for everything I tried.

Comment: @Emigna Actually, I can leave the entire flatten out, since the leading zeros will still be removed by the int haha.

Comment: Actually, is it really OK to remove all zeroes? I don't have an example but couldn't one number end up with the same digits as the other numbers apart from an extra zero?

Comment: Consider the number `0212765957446808510638297872340425531914893617` as mentioned in the comments of another answer. Looking at the sorted numbers I would assume it to return false, but when removing zeroes it becomes true.

Comment: @Emigna Hm, that's weird, because you can always add extra zeros in front of the number to equalize the number of zeros. At least, that's how I understood the question.

Comment: @tfbninja Is the output for Emigna's test case truthy or falsy?

Comment: @Emigna, and Adnan  I checked, and it is a cyclic number, at least, according to Wikipedia, which I know isn't the best source but it's one of the only options. So, truthy

Comment: @Adnan: Ah yes, I didn't consider that :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 18 bytes

```
;;ru@≈*♂$♂S♂≈╔@S≈=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/9/auqjU4VFnh9ajmU0qQBwMxEDuo6lTHIKBtO3//0oGphYWRsamRpYmhobmZibmSgA) (expects quoted input)

Explanation:

```
;;ru@≈*♂$♂S♂≈╔@S≈=
;;                  duplicate input twice
  ru                range(1, len(input)+1)
    @≈              convert input to an integer
      *             multiply input by each element in range
       ♂$♂S♂≈       convert each product to a string, sort the digits, and convert back to int
             ╔      uniquify: remove duplicate elements
              @S≈   sort input and convert to int
                 =  compare equality
```

Comment: @tfbninja I posted this before the bit about leading zeroes. I have another 15-byte solution that will work with leading zeroes that I will edit in soon.

Comment: What character encoding do you use to achieve 18 bytes? I tried UTF-8 and it weighed in at 32 bytes. EDIT: Oh, I see, it's code page 437.

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 86 bytes

```python
lambda n:all(sorted(n)==sorted(str(int(n)*i).zfill(len(n)))for i in range(2,len(n)+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/IV8r/2)

Input numbers as strings.

Comment: @tfbninja should work on any python (2 and 3)

Comment: why does it fail with 0212765957446808510638297872340425531914893617 ?

Comment: @Jenny_mathy now it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 64 Bytes

```php
for(;$i++<9;)$r+=($c=count_chars)($argn)==$c($argn*$i);echo$r>1;
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f7a770a17415bbc9b9b3a5d484afac92e49d30a5)

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <strike>36</strike> <strike>33</strike> <strike>32</strike> 45 bytes

```
c n=let l=length n in(10^l-1)`div`read n==l+1
```

Example usage:

```
*Main> c "142857"
True
```

I don't think this algorithm needs any explanation.

[TOL](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1khzzYntUQhB0jmpZdkKOQpZOZpGBrE5egaaiakZJYlaORoG2ra2halJqYo5P3/DwA)

Thanks for suggestions: Generic Display Name, Laikoni.

Thanks for correction: Antony Hatchkins.

**EDIT** Nope, fails on "33".

Comment: does it work for 052631578947368421 ?

Comment: Yes, it returns True in that case.

Comment: Save some bytes by replacing ns with n

Comment: Can you use `<1` instead of `==0`? Also here is a TIO link: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLCoAgFAXQrdxBgxoUvuxjUFuJRCUjfUIJLd/O8fq9XQilGPBWk9iD4zN7cEvNEZM9HqcteKUS9cXYcHF2jzYZFV6fPnQwRYz9JGmc1TLMclJDTz8 "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: How about 111111?

Comment: Ah, good point. It needs to be the minimum period, not the length of the input number.

Answer (score 2):

## dc, <strike>24</strike> 25 bytes

```
[1]sa0?dZd10r^1-r1+/rx=ap
```

Prints "0" if the number is not cyclic, otherwise "1". Requires the number to be entered as a string.

Example usage:

```
$ echo "[052631578947368421]" | dc -e '[1]sa0?dZd10r^1-r1+/rx=ap'
1
$ echo "[052631578947368422]" | dc -e '[1]sa0?dZd10r^1-r1+/rx=ap'
0
```

[TOL](https://tio.run/nexus/dc#@x9tGFucaGCfEpViaFAUZ6hbZKitX1Rhm1jw/z8A)

Explanation: Same algorithm as my Haskell submission.

EDIT Nope, fails on "33".

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 81 bytes

```
Length@Union@PadLeft[Sort/@IntegerDigits[ToExpression@#*Range@StringLength@#]]<2&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvvfJzUvvSTDITQvMz/PISAxxSc1rSQ6OL@oRN/BM68kNT21yCUzPbOkODok37WioCi1uBikUFkrKDEvPdUhuKQoMy8daoZybKyNkdr/AKBQiYJDmoOSgYmxibmFkZmBhZmlqZmpkaG5saWhsdJ/AA)

input string

**Input**

> "010309278350515463917525773195876288659793814432989690721649484536082474226804123711340206185567"

**Output**

> True

Comment: `FromDigits` is shorter than `ToExpression`

Comment: because in this challenge you need to work with inputs like 034324...

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 85 bytes

```scala
n=>(2 to n.size).forall(i=>n.sorted==(BigInt(n)*i).toString.padTo(n.size,'0').sorted)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bY-9TsMwFIXF2pEnuMpSG9Eo_ncqORLdGJigU9XBtEllFOzKMSBAfRKWMsDCE8HTEJFOqMs9uud-50j37bNb2dayr0U28eHJRp8tf05Ow-1dvUpwZZ2H1xHAum7gvl-QjZtuChcx2ufFdYrOb5Z4CnPvEpg_EmDbu6n1qEEZ4VQLlWH8_1AIrSkTtOSEKMmPI1QyIpQuuWJSc0qOQZxxpakstCyFFJQoVhJ2DGSca6qElrSQupRCEEU5Yapkh97dqB-PtoVmCmh4zVSzENraegzm4yE1E_0996ZCFFIAn3fupcZ5E6JtW-RM1TshpnptDJq5zaVPyOMzh_MUhrp8a9c3AQ3B83ExxocAHsrfd4Pu94P-Ag)